# Async calls in loop delayed

Tags: javascript, database, async-await, knex.js

I have a function which makes two asynchronous calls to the database inside a loop. The issue is that the return function works before the data from the loop is retrieved.

```
const myFunc = async (customers) => {
  const customerList = customers.map(async (customer) => {
    const cashCollected = await knex('cash_collections')
      .sum('amount_collected as amount')
      .where('account_code', customer.code)
      .first();
    const orderValue = await knex('orders')
      .sum('discounted_price as amount')
      .where('customer_id', customer.id)
      .first();
    const customerData = {
      name: customer.name,
      outstandingBalance: (orderValue.amount - cashCollected.amount),
    };
    // This line works after console.log(customerList);
    console.log(customerData);
    return customerData;
  });
   // console and return works before data is retrieved 
   // (before console.log(customerData) is run)
  console.log(customerList);
  return customerList;
};

// Function is called in another place
myFunc()
```

Comment: On SO, we don't fold parts of answers into the question. We leave them separate. Happy coding!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making all of those calls in parallel by doing them in the `map` callback. If you really want to do that, you need to wait for those calls to settle by using `Promise.all`:

```
const customerList = await Promise.all(customers.map(async (customer) => {
    // ...
}));
```

If you want to do them in series instead, use a `for` loop and await each response. :-) But it looks like parallel is okay.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` the map and then it will wait for it otherwise being async doesn't make it wait it actually means it *will* go on to the next code unless you tell it to `await`. like so:
`const customerList = await customers.map....`
Now since map does not return a promise you would need to wrap it in a promise either with `Promise.all` or an individual promise.

Comment: `map` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: The edit still has `await customers.map`, which won't do anything useful I'm afraid. You want to wait for the promises in the array that `map` returns (I did that in my answer via `Promise.all`, for instance).